# how to auto close menu children sidebar in vue js

Tags: vue.js

I have a sidebar with children.
The problem is when I click on a menu, I have to click on it again to close it.
how so that when I click on another menu all of the children sidebar dropdowns are closed except for the ones I clicked on.

sorry my English is bad

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-9prim)

Comment: You could try a similar approach as recommended here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51774458/vuejs-set-active-class-when-one-li-element-clicked-in-v-for-loop/51774644

Answer (score 0):

you can use @mouseover insted of @click